# Calling super() without a base class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working through the O Reilly *Python Cookbook* and have been struggling with the below code. It is to with calling a method on a parent class using `super()`:

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

    # Delegate attribute lookup to internal obj
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._obj, name)

    # Delegate attribute assignment
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name.startswith('_'):
            super().__setattr__(name, value)    # Call original __setattr__
        else:
            setattr(self._obj, name, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    class A:
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x
        def spam(self):
            print('A.spam')

    a = A(42)
    p = Proxy(a)
    print(p.x)
    print(p.spam())
    p.x = 37
    print('Should be 37:', p.x)
    print('Should be 37:', a.x)
```

The book states:

> In this code the implementation of `__setatrr__()` includes a name
>   check. If the name starts with an underscore it invokes the original
>   implementation of `__setattr__()` using `super()`. Otherwise, it delegates
>   to the internally held object `self._obj`.

I am confused. How does `super()` work then if there is no explicit base class listed?
What exactly then is `super()` referring to?

Comment: There's *always* a base class, and the whole point of `super` is that you don't need to know which class `super()` will refer to. `Proxy` inherits directly from `object`, but that doesn't mean `Proxy` will appear immediately before `object` in the MRO of `self`. (`self` could be an instance of some class that inherits from many classes in addition to `Proxy`.)

Answer (score 3):

There is always a base class; with none explicitly mentioned, `Proxy` inherits directly from `object`.

Each class defines a method-resolution order, determined recursively by its base class(es) and its ancestors. When `super()` gets called, it resolves to a "proxy" of the next class in the MRO of `self`, whether or not that class appears in the MRO of the class you are currently defining.

Consider the following classes:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        print("A.foo")


class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("B.foo")


class C(A):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("C.foo")


class D(C):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("D.foo")


class E(B,D):
    def foo(self):
        super().foo()
        print("E.foo")

e = E()
```

The MRO of `E` is `[E, B, D, C, A, object]`. When you call `e.foo()`, you start a chain of calls in MRO order. In particular, the call to `super` in `B.foo` does not invoke `A.foo`, but `D.foo`, a method in a class `B` knows nothing about, as `D` is not an ancestor of `B`. But both `B` and `D` are ancestors of `E`, which is what matters.